# ImageSearch on screen and get position on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, screen

There is a equivalent to do like in autohotkey:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm
For NodeJS?

On that u can pass a image as parameter and it return if something on screen matches with this image and shows the position

If there was a function like that it would help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

use this module in node js:

[node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)

[robotjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs)

this module for image processing and and read the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Also check NutJS screen functionality.

https://nutjs.dev/apidoc/screen#find
https://nut-tree.github.io/apidoc/classes/screen_class.ScreenClass.html#find